# Target JSON object with variable property

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON object with a list of countries :

```
"countries": {
        "AQ": {"name": "Antarctica", n: 0, current: 1},
        "AF": {"name": "Afghanistan", n: 2, current: 1},
        "AL": {"name": "Albania", n: 3, current: 1},
}

load >>

countriesDB = json.datas.countries
```

I need to get the `n` and the `current` of an item. `countriesDB.AQ.n` works, of course. But the caller is from another db ; `events[0].e[0]` gives me `"AQ"`. So what I'd like to do is something like that : `countriesDB.(events[0].e[0]).n`.

This is certainly pretty simple but I cannot figure out how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
countriesDB[events[0].e[0]].n
```

?